# try-multicatch with ExceptionInInitializerError and ArithmeticException confusion

Tags: java, try-catch, static-initialization, arithmeticexception

```
public class HelloWorld {
   static {
    try {
        int i=10/0;
     } catch(ExceptionInInitializerError | ArithmeticException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
   } 

   public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:7)
```

There is no actual purpose to this code. But just wondered why it threw `ArithmeticException` over `ExceptionInInitializerError`. 
Just trying out multi-catch statement and ran into this.

The code below throws `ExceptionInInitializerError`. So logically, if I use try-multicatch, it should catch `ExceptionInInitializerError`, but its not the case here. Can anyone help me out here.

```
public class HelloWorld {

     static int i = 10/0;

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
     }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError                                                                                                   
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero                                                                                                                
        at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:4)
```

Comment: As a guess, the real exception (`ArithmeticException`) is thrown first.  When you don't catch it, it gets wrapped in `ExceptionInInitializerError` at the completion of the static initialization.  If however you DO catch it you are immediately printing the stack trace _while still in the static initialization code_.  Did you look further down to see if you then got `ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static
{
    try
    {
        int i = 10 / 0;
    }
    catch (ExceptionInInitializerError | ArithmeticException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This causes an `ArithmeticException` but since you catch it, there is not problem with the Initialization.

```
static
{
    int i = 10 / 0;
}
```

This causes an `ArithmeticException` but since you do not catch it, the `ArithmeticException` causes an `ExceptionInInitializerError`. You can see it from the stack shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at src.Test.<clinit>(Test.java:23)
```

Answer (score 3):

When a static initializer of a class fails with an exception, an `ExceptionInInitializerError` that wraps the original exception is thrown. In your first snippet, there is no failure in the static initialization block - the same `ArithmeticException` is thrown by attempting to perform `10/0`, but it is caught and not allowed to propagate out of the initialization block, so no `ExceptionInInitializerError` is generated.

Answer (score 2):

The code `i=10/0` throws an `ArithmeticException`.

When you use that without a try-catch, then there is nothing to handle that exception. An uncaught exception while initializing causes an `ExceptionInInitializerError`. As you can see, the error carries the original `ArithmeticException` as its cause.

But when you have `try-catch`, then you no longer have this problem. There is no unhandled exception in the code - it is handled by your try-catch. Thus, you see the original exception that would have caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

The state i=10/0  throws only ArithmeticException , so your try catch catches the ArithmeticException  not the ExceptionInInitializerError.

when there is no try catch it is caught by default Exception handler.